# Kibana Fatal error Unknown provider: sessionTimeoutProvider

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

After upgrading Kibana, Elastsearch and Logstash to 5.x I'm running into the following issue while trying to access the Kibana web ui:

```
Error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: sessionTimeoutProvider <- sessionTimeout <- $http <- config
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=sessionTimeoutProvider%20%3C-%20sessionTimeout%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20config (https://logstash.replaced.com/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=14458:36)
at window.onerror (https://logstash.replaced.com/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=14458:69:13503)
```

I've restarted nginx and all of the services and they all seem to be running fine locally with no error in logs.

Comment: You've pointed the `Kibana` instance to your ES right ?

Comment: @Kulasangar I have yes

Comment: Seems like there's a workaround [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/6445), since this has been a known issue.